# toggle value of button Jquery

Tags: jquery, html-input

I want to toggle the value of button using the jquery toggle functions, but it doesn't works

my button is as follows:

```
<input type="button" value="Click to send message"  id="send_message_button">
```

Now I want to toggle the *Click to send message* to *Click to hide message* with jquery, is this possible ?

Comment: toggle is used to toggle between two entities. but here you only want to change the value of a button to something else on a click. so the below answers are fine. find jQuery toggle [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: Yes it is possible but i think jquery toggle is not the best way to solve this, because the property u want to change is value and not class.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean toggle like it reverts back when you clicked it again. Try this:

```
var clicked = false;
$('#send_message_button').click(function(){
    $(this).val("Click to "+ (clicked? "send": "hide") + " message");
    clicked = !clicked;
});
```

Comment: very nice and neat answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think its bit tricky with toggle function. I have created a fiddle for you please check.

http://jsfiddle.net/8udzL/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#send_message_button').click(function () {

    if ($('#send_message_button').val() == "Click to send message") {
        $('#send_message_button').val("Click to hide message");
    } 
    else
    {
    $('#send_message_button').val("Click to send message");
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Its too much to write. See the Nix's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/QcUtc/

```
<input type="button" value="Click to send message"  id="send_message_button">

$('#send_message_button').click(function(){
    $(this).val("Click to hide message");  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="Click to send message" OnClick="toggle()"  id="send_message_button">

function toggle(){
    $('#send_message_button').val("Click to hide message");  
}
```

Comment: [Toggle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toggle) implies _alternation between two states_, but your solution doesn't change the value back to the original value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, that it'll be nice solution, but read it as one of the cases.
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfBAy/)

**Add data attribute:**

```
<input type="button" value="Click to send message" data-value="Click to hide message"  id="send_message_button" />
```

**Js code:**

```
$('#send_message_button').on('click', function(){
    $(this).val((function(input) {var alt = $(input).data('value'); $(input).data('value', $(input).val()); return alt;})(this))  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello try this: http://jsfiddle.net/zander_pope/udu5cchh/

```
$(function () {
    $('.button').on('click', function (e) {
        if (!$('.dd').val()) {
            $('.dd').val("relevance");
        } else {
            $('.dd').val("");
        }
    });
});
$(function () {
    $('.button').on('click', function (e) {
        $('.search').click();
    });
});
```

This will work and can be adapted to your code.